# ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I get following error

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(2)]), dtype=int32)'
```

when I try to calculate cross entropy loss

```
losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(scores, input_y)
```

I use Python 3.4.3.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It sounds like you have defined `input_y`—which I am assuming is a `tf.placeholder()`—as having type `tf.int32`. Either change this to `tf.float32` or add a [cast](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#cast): `tf.cast(input_y, tf.float32)` or `tf.to_float(input_y)`.

Comment: i can't find cast or to_float in tflearn, which module do we have to import?

Comment: `tf.cast()` and `tf.to_float()` are TensorFlow functions, so you'd get them using `import tensorflow as tf`.

Comment: you can also define the datatype while assignment `dtype=tf.float32`

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `%tensorflow_version 1.x` in my code with `!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5` and the error disappeared. Not limited to just version 1.15.5, it works for some other TensorFlow version 1s as well.